# Angular 9 error mde-popover is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material, popover

I am working with angular 9 and I want to have a popover with a delete and edit option in it whenever someone hovers over a `mat-card`. I imported `mdePopoverModule` in `app.module.ts` but when I want to use `<mde-popover>`

it gives me this error :

[image]

HTML :

```
<mat-card 
  [mdePopoverTriggerFor]="appPopover" 
  class="skill-name" 
  *ngFor="let skillcard of skillcolumn.items">
  <mat-card-content>{{skillcard.skill}}</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>

<mde-popover #appPopover="mdePopover">
  <p>test </p>
</mde-popover>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { MdePopoverModule } from '@material-extended/mde';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MyMaterialModule,
    MdePopoverModule,
  ],
```

Anyone who knows what I could do to fix this error?

Comment: You will need to add `MdePopoverModule` to closest module where you are using this.

Comment: Yes! I was so focussed on app.module.ts that I forgot that I'm working with several different modules in my app. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem here would be the scope of module which you are working on, try importing the module into the module that your component needs the popover.